# Best way to perform multiple time taking operations for every single item in a large array

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, asynchronous, time-complexity

I have a function in my javascript code that loops through an array and performs some time-taking actions on each item of the array. It works fine for now when the number of items is low in the array but I also want the code to work if the the array is larger. Here is my function:

```
const fetchAndProcessNews = async (queryString, from) => {
  const query = {
    queryString,
    from,
    size: 1,
  }
  try {
    console.log('Fetching news...')
    const { articles } = await searchApi.getNews(query)
    console.log('total articles fetched:', articles.length)
    console.log('Fetched news:', articles)
    if (articles && articles.length > 0) {
      console.log('Processing news...')
      //looping through all the articles fetched from api
      for (const article of articles) {
        console.log('Processing article with name: ', article.title)
        const { title, sourceUrl, id, publishedAt } = article
        //scraping content from the source url and returning the markup of the single article
        const markup = await scraper(sourceUrl)
        //using gpt to perform some tasks on the markup returned from scrapping
        const data = await askGpt(markup)
        //using dall e to generate an image
        const generatedImageUrl = await generateImg(data?.imageDescription)
        //downloading the image from the url and uploading it to s3
        const s3ImageUrl = await generateImgUrl(generatedImageUrl, title, id)
        //uploading the article to strapi using post request
        const newTitle = data?.title
        const newMarkup = data?.content
        const description = data?.abstract
        const categories = data?.categories

        console.log('pushing article to strapi')
        await createPost(
          newTitle,
          description,
          newMarkup,
          s3ImageUrl,
          publishedAt,
          categories
        )
        console.log('article processsing completed...')
      }
    } else {
      console.log('No articles found')
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching news:', error.message)
  }
}
```

let me explain what I am doing i am fetching some news articles from an api and for every article I perform these tasks:

1. scrape the content using a URL provided by the api using Cheerio which takes some time
2. use open AI to perform some tasks on the markup which also takes a lot of time.
3. generate an image using dall e which also takes time
4. then i upload the image to s3
5. then I upload all the things to strapi using post-request

Now I am worried about if the number of articles is let's say 100 or 1000 how will this code work? will it be able to handle all of these time-consuming tasks? How can I make it more optimal so that it does not crash and works normally? I don't have that much experience that's why I am a little bit worried. What techniques should I use? Should I use some kind of queue like bull js or batch processing? Please if somebody can provide a detailed answer it will be a big help.

Comment: I would suggest implementing parallel programming using `Promise.all` to perform concurrent tasks. Also, you can leverage some message queues or task schedulers to enhance your scheduling and task execution efficiently.

Comment: hey @mandy8055 thanks for replying. I have read somewhere that promise.all will be rejected immediately if any of the promises in the array are rejected. If one of the asynchronous operations fails (throws an error or returns a rejected promise), the entire Promise. all will reject. I am not sure about this. Can you confirm is right or wrong or how to make sure that if any one item fails the other continue.

Comment: Yes that's correct. **how to make sure that if any one item fails the other continue?** [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) or [Promise.any](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any)

Comment: But my point was to use `Promise.all` because I wanted to process articles simultaneously(only after fetching the articles successfully) so that the performance would be better. If you want I can write the answer explaning how I would go about it. The thing is this is suggestions based and open-ended question

Comment: @saimarshadd ... Regarding all the answers / approaches, are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to not wait for all steps of article processing to complete before starting the processing of a next article.

You could for instance start with a next article at each passing of 100 milliseconds. You could even start them all without delay, but the risk is that you may make too many requests to the same server, hitting some server limit. So it is probably more prudent to have a slight delay between the initiations of article processing. To have such intermediate delay, you could use this general purpose function:

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

The easiest way to accomplish the overall idea, is to put the code for article processing in a separate function:

```
const processArticle = async (article) = {
    console.log('Processing article with name: ', article.title)
    const { title, sourceUrl, id, publishedAt } = article
    //scraping content from the source url and returning the markup of the single article
    const markup = await scraper(sourceUrl)
    //using gpt to perform some tasks on the markup returned from scrapping
    const data = await askGpt(markup)
    //using dall e to generate an image
    const generatedImageUrl = await generateImg(data?.imageDescription)
    //downloading the image from the url and uploading it to s3
    const s3ImageUrl = await generateImgUrl(generatedImageUrl, title, id)
    //uploading the article to strapi using post request
    const newTitle = data?.title
    const newMarkup = data?.content
    const description = data?.abstract
    const categories = data?.categories

    console.log('pushing article to strapi')
    await createPost(
      newTitle,
      description,
      newMarkup,
      s3ImageUrl,
      publishedAt,
      categories
    )
    console.log('article processing completed...')
};
```

No code was changed here; it was just moved into a function.

Now your main function can execute the above function *without awaiting it*. Instead it can capture the promise it returns (which will be pending), and collect such promises in an array. This means several requests will now be made for different articles without awaiting their responses. Finally you will probably want to await that *all* these promises have settled.

Here is how your original function would look:

```
const fetchAndProcessNews = async (queryString, from) => {
  const query = {
    queryString,
    from,
    size: 1,
  }
  try {
    console.log('Fetching news...')
    const { articles } = await searchApi.getNews(query)
    console.log('total articles fetched:', articles.length)
    console.log('Fetched news:', articles)
    if (articles && articles.length > 0) {
      console.log('Processing news...')
      // looping through all the articles fetched from api
      const promises = [];
      for (const article of articles) {
        promises.push(processArticle(article)); // We don't await!
        await delay(100); // Determine which delay is suitable
      }
      // All articles are now being processed; wait for all to finish (optional)
      await promise.allSettled(promises);
    } else {
      console.log('No articles found')
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching news:', error.message)
  }
}
```

The `await Promise.allSettled` operation is optional, but it will be useful for the caller of `fetchAndProcessNews`, as then the promise they get in return will only resolve when all is done.

On a final note, you'll probably want to improve the `console.log` output made in `processArticle` as now they will get interwoven, and it will be useful to see which article the messages "pushing article to strapi" and "article processsing completed..." are about.

Answer (score 0):

One might try both ...

- separating the asynchronous/deferred post-data calculation of to be scraped articles from uploading the calculated post-data
- and parallelizing post-data calculations and post api-calls alike.

A possible solution first does implement a function which calculates any to be scraped article's post-data.

A convenient approach for parallelizing post-data calculations while also trying to not entirely overload/block the API might come with the combined usage of an [async generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function*), the returned [async generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncGenerator) and [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

One does create batches of parallel deferred post-data calculations by [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)ing **`N`** article items at time from an array of to be scraped articles (the ones initially derived from the first api-call).

As long as there are article-items within the constantly mutated article-array, the async generator yields a promise of all **`N`** asynchronous/deferred post-data calculations where **`N`** is the batch size.

Iterating the async generator with the [`for await...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) statement gives access to an array of resolved post-data. Thus, one now can try parallelizing the post api calls as well by creating a promise of all api-calls, each having gotten passed its related `args`-array of resolved post-data.

```js
// implementation of just the business/problem specifc logic.

async function getArticlePostParametersDeferred(article) {
  const { title, sourceUrl, id, publishedAt } = article;

  console.log(`Get post-data of article "${ title }".`);

  // nothing here which could be further parallelized.
  const markup = await scraper(sourceUrl);
  const data = await askGpt(markup, title); // cheating `title` into it for demonstration purpose.

  const generatedImageUrl = await generateImg(data?.imageDescription);
  const s3ImageUrl = await generateImgUrl(generatedImageUrl, title, id);

  // the post-data derieved from a scraped article.
  return [
    data?.title, data?.abstract, data?.content,
    s3ImageUrl, publishedAt, data?.categories,
  ];
}

async function* createDeferredBatchesOfParallelRetrievedArticlePostData(
  articleList = [], batchSize = 4, // play with the batch size.
) {
  while (articleList.length >= 1) {

    // - try to parallelize the calculation of article post-data by creating
    //   `Promise.all` based batches of deferred post-data calculations.

    yield await Promise.all(
      articleList.splice(0, batchSize).map(getArticlePostParametersDeferred)
    );
  }
}

async function fetchAndProcessNews(queryString, from) {
  const query = { queryString, from, size: 1 };

  try {
    const fetchTime = Date.now();
    console.log('... start fetching and processing ...');

    const { articles } = await searchApi.getNews(query);

    if (articles && articles.length > 0) {

      const deferredPostDataPool =
        createDeferredBatchesOfParallelRetrievedArticlePostData([...articles]);

      // ... separate the (parallelized and batched) post-data calculation ...

      for await (const resolvedPostParametersList of deferredPostDataPool) {

        const batchTime = Date.now();
        console.log("... next batch ...");

        // ... from posting an article's new data;
        //     but here too, trying to parallelize the post api calls.

        // - one should give it a try playing around with delaying a bit each
        //   batch of post-data uploads in case one runs into API blocking issues. 
        //
        // await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500)); // waits for 500 msec.

        // - one also intentionally does omit the awaiting of `Promis.all`.
        //
        // - but one might change it back to `await` and notice the difference.

        /* await */Promise.all(
          resolvedPostParametersList.map(postParams => createPost(...postParams))
        );
        console.log(`... batch process time ... ${ Date.now() - batchTime } msec ...`);
        console.log(`... fetch process time ... ${ Date.now() - fetchTime } msec ...`);
      }
      console.log(`... fetch process total ... ${ Date.now() - fetchTime } msec ...`);

    } else {
      console.error('No articles found.');
    }
  } catch (reason) {

    console.error(`Error while fetching news due to ... "${ reason }"`);
  }
}
fetchAndProcessNews();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
  // mocking an entire api environment.

  const scraper = async (url) =>
    new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(resolve, (Math.random() * 500), '<markup\/>')
    );

  const askGpt = async (markup, mockedTitle) =>
    new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(resolve, (Math.random() * 500), {
        imageDescription: 'foo bar',
        title: mockedTitle,
        abstract: 'TLDR',
        content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
        categories: ['asynchronous', 'performance', 'test'],
      })
    );

  const generateImg = async (description) => {
    const name = `${ description.split(/\s+/).join('-').replace(/[^\w-]/g, '') }.jpg`;

    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, (Math.random() * 500), name));
  };
  const generateImgUrl = async (name, title, id) => {
    title = title.split(/\s+/).join('-').replace(/[^\w-]/g, '');

    return new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(resolve, (Math.random() * 500), `s3/bucket/images/${ id }/${ title }/${ name }`)
    );
  };

  const createPost = async (...args) => {
    console.log(`Posting scraped article data from arguments ... ["${ args.join('", "') }"]`);

    return new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(() => {

        console.log(`Article data posted successfully for title "${ args[0] }"`);
        resolve({ title: args[0] });

      }, (Math.random() * 2000))
    );
  };

  const searchApi = {
    getNews: async (query) =>
      new Promise(resolve =>
        setTimeout(resolve, (Math.random() * 1500), {
        //articles: [],
          articles: [{
            title: '01) Lorem Ipsum',
            sourceUrl: 'foo/bar/baz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '02) Dolor sit amet',
            sourceUrl: 'biz/buzz/booz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '03) Lorem Ipsum',
            sourceUrl: 'foo/bar/baz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '04) Dolor sit amet',
            sourceUrl: 'biz/buzz/booz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '05) Lorem Ipsum',
            sourceUrl: 'foo/bar/baz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '06) Dolor sit amet',
            sourceUrl: 'biz/buzz/booz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '07) Lorem Ipsum',
            sourceUrl: 'foo/bar/baz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '08) Dolor sit amet',
            sourceUrl: 'biz/buzz/booz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '09) Lorem Ipsum',
            sourceUrl: 'foo/bar/baz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '10) Dolor sit amet',
            sourceUrl: 'biz/buzz/booz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '11) Lorem Ipsum',
            sourceUrl: 'foo/bar/baz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '12) Dolor sit amet',
            sourceUrl: 'biz/buzz/booz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '13) Lorem Ipsum',
            sourceUrl: 'foo/bar/baz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }],
        })
      ),
  };
</script>
```

**Note**

An even better solution would entirely decouple the scraping from the post-data upload. The code which consumes the async generator then needs to be changed into feeding each batch of resolved post-data arguments into a queue. The latter then needs to be implemented in a way that it is aware of post-data items getting enqueued and that it continuously keeps uploading post-data items in an efficient (parallel uploads) way as long as there are still items present.

**Edit**

The next provided example code implements the above mentioned queue-based approach. It does so by providing a generic abstraction of what one could call an ***"Async Task Execution Queue"*** which can be used by both of the decoupled overall tasks, the ***scraping** of all articles* and the ***posting** of all calculated, article related parameters*. The price for achieving a strong decoupling is payed with the usage of event-dispatching. Thus, the `AsyncTaskExecutionQueue` extends `EventTarget`.

The OP's original `fetchAndProcessNews` function was re-implemented as async function which just rejects in case of failing at the initial `articles`-fetch or in case of having fetched an empty `articles`-array; otherwise it's always going to show an ***"all settled"** behavior*, regardless of scraping and/or posting failures. The new implementation of `fetchAndProcessNews` demonstrates how one achieves such a behavior despite both queues being decoupled strongly via event-dispatching.

The main techniques are ...

- making use of [`Promise.withResolvers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/withResolvers),
- updating and counting the various task totals and comparing them to the total article count,

... which both enable a clean(er) syntax for returning a promise which can be either resolved or rejected depending on the correct task counts in case of the former (`resolve`) and on the before mentioned critical errors in case of the latter (`reject`).

```js
// implementation of just the business/problem specifc logic.

async function getArticlePostParametersDeferred(article) {
  const { title, sourceUrl, id, publishedAt } = article;

  console.log(`Get post-data of article "${ title }".`);

  // nothing here which could be further parallelized.
  const markup = await scraper(sourceUrl);
  const data = await askGpt(markup, title); // cheating `title` into it for demonstration purpose.

  const generatedImageUrl = await generateImg(data?.imageDescription);
  const s3ImageUrl = await generateImgUrl(generatedImageUrl, title, id);

  // the post-data derieved from a scraped article.
  return [
    data?.title, data?.abstract, data?.content,
    s3ImageUrl, publishedAt, data?.categories,
  ];
}

async function fetchAndProcessNews(queryString, from) {
  // implemented similar to `Promise.allSettled`.
  const { promise, resolve, reject } = Promise.withResolvers();

  const allSettledData = {
    scraping: { resolved: [], rejected: [] },
    posting: { resolved: [], rejected: [] },
  };
  let articleCount = -1;

  function settleAllIfPossible() {
    const {
      scraping: {
        resolved: { length: scrapingResolvedCount },
        rejected: { length: scrapingRejectedCount },
      },
      posting: {
        resolved: { length: postingResolvedCount },
        rejected: { length: postingRejectedCount },
      },
    } = allSettledData;

    if (
      (scrapingResolvedCount + scrapingRejectedCount === articleCount) &&
      (postingResolvedCount + postingRejectedCount === articleCount)
    ) {
      resolve(allSettledData);
    }
  }
  // play with the queues' batch sizes.

  // - e.g. batch size of 3 for post requests.
  const postTaskQueue = new AsyncTaskExecutionQueue(3);   // 4
  // - e.g. batch size of 5 for scraping requests.
  const scrapeTaskQueue = new AsyncTaskExecutionQueue(5); // 4

  postTaskQueue
    .addEventListener('rejected', ({ detail: { reasons: postFailureList } }) => {

      allSettledData.posting.rejected.push(...postFailureList);
      console.log({ postFailureList });

      settleAllIfPossible();
    });
  postTaskQueue
    .addEventListener('resolved', ({ detail: { values: postResponseList } }) => {

      allSettledData.posting.resolved.push(...postResponseList);
      console.log({ postResponseList });

      settleAllIfPossible();
    });

  scrapeTaskQueue
    .addEventListener('rejected', ({ detail: { reasons: scrapeFailureList } }) => {

      allSettledData.scraping.rejected.push(...scrapeFailureList);
      console.log({ scrapeFailureList });

      settleAllIfPossible();
    });
  scrapeTaskQueue
    .addEventListener('resolved', ({ detail: { values: postParamsList } }) => {

      postTaskQueue
        .enqueue(
          postParamsList
            .map(postParams => ({
              createAsynTask: createPost,
              params: postParams,
            }))
        );

      allSettledData.scraping.resolved.push(...postParamsList);
      // console.log({ postParamsList });

      settleAllIfPossible();
    });

  try {
    const { articles } = await searchApi.getNews({ queryString, from, size: 1 });

    if (articles) {
      articleCount = articles.length;

      if (articleCount > 0) {

        scrapeTaskQueue
          .enqueue(
            [...articles]
              .map(article => ({
                createAsynTask: getArticlePostParametersDeferred,
                params: [article],
              }))
          );

      } else {
        reject('No articles found.');
      }
    } else {
      reject('Internal error.');
    }
  } catch (reason) {

    reject(reason);
  }
  return promise;
}


(async () => {
  console.log('... start fetching and processing ...');
  const timestamp = Date.now();

  try {
    const allSettledData = await fetchAndProcessNews();

    console.log(`... total fetching and processing time ... ${ Date.now() - timestamp } msec ...`);
    console.log({ allSettledData });

  } catch (reason) {

    console.log(`... total fetching and processing time ... ${ Date.now() - timestamp } msec ...`);
    console.error({ reason });
  }
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
  // helper/utility funtionality.

  function isFunction(value) {
    return (
      (typeof value === 'function') &&
      (typeof value.call === 'function') &&
      (typeof value.apply === 'function')
    );
  }
  function isAsynFunction(value) {
    return (/\[object\s+AsyncFunction\]/).test(
      Object.prototype.toString.call(value)
    );
  }

  function throttle(proceed, threshold = 200, target) {
    let timeoutId = null;
    let referenceTime = 0;

    return (isAsynFunction(proceed) && async function throttled(...args) {
      const currentTime = Date.now();

      if (currentTime - referenceTime >= threshold) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);

        referenceTime = currentTime;
        const trigger = proceed.bind((target ?? this), ...args);

        timeoutId = setTimeout((() => {

          referenceTime = 0;
          trigger();

        }), threshold);

        trigger();
      }
    }) || (isFunction(proceed) && function throttled(...args) {
      const currentTime = Date.now();

      if (currentTime - referenceTime >= threshold) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);

        referenceTime = currentTime;
        const trigger = proceed.bind((target ?? this), ...args);

        timeoutId = setTimeout((() => {

          referenceTime = 0;
          trigger();

        }), threshold);

        trigger();
      }
    }) || proceed;
  }

  function getValuesAndReasons(settledItems) {
    return settledItems
      .reduce(({ values, reasons }, { value, reason = null }) => {

        if (reason !== null) {
          reasons.push(reason);
        } else {
          values.push(value);
        }
        return { values, reasons };

      }, { values: [], reasons: [] });
  }
</script>

<script>
  // abstraction of an "Async Task Execution Queue".

  async function* generateAsyncTaskBatches(taskComponents, batchSize) {
    while (taskComponents.length >= 1) {

      // - try to parallelize the execution of asynchronous tasks by creating
      //   `Promise.allSettled` based arrays of deferred task execution values.

      yield await Promise.allSettled(
        taskComponents
          .splice(0, batchSize)
          .map(({ createAsynTask, params }) => createAsynTask(...params))
      );
    }
  }

  async function generateExecuteAndNotifyAsyncTasks() {
    const { queue, taskComponents, batchSize } = this;

    const deferredResultsPool =
      generateAsyncTaskBatches(taskComponents, batchSize);

    for await (const settledItems of deferredResultsPool) {
      // console.log({ settledItems });

      queue
        .dispatchEvent(
          new CustomEvent('settled', { detail: { results: settledItems } })
        );

      const { values, reasons } = getValuesAndReasons(settledItems);

      if (values.length > 0) {
        queue
          .dispatchEvent(
            new CustomEvent('resolved', { detail: { values } })
          );
      }
      if (reasons.length > 0) {
        queue
          .dispatchEvent(
            new CustomEvent('rejected', { detail: { reasons } })
          );
      }
    }
  }

  class AsyncTaskExecutionQueue extends EventTarget {
    #processQueue;
    #taskComponents = [];

    constructor(batchSize = 4, throttleThreshold = 0) {
      super();

      this.#processQueue = throttle(
        generateExecuteAndNotifyAsyncTasks.bind({
          queue: this, taskComponents: this.#taskComponents, batchSize,
        }),
        throttleThreshold,
      );
    }
    enqueue(...args) {
      const taskComponents = args
        .flat()
        .filter(({ createAsynTask, params }) =>
          isFunction(createAsynTask) && Array.isArray(params)
        );

      if (taskComponents.length > 0) {
        this.#taskComponents.push(...taskComponents);
        this.#processQueue();
      }
    }  
  }
</script>

<script>
  // mocking an entire api environment.

  const scraper = async (url) =>
    new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(resolve, (Math.random() * 1500), '<markup\/>')
    );

  const askGpt = async (markup, mockedTitle) =>
    new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(resolve, (Math.random() * 1500), {
        imageDescription: 'foo bar',
        title: mockedTitle,
        abstract: 'TLDR',
        content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
        categories: ['asynchronous', 'performance', 'test'],
      })
    );

  const generateImg = async (description) => {
    const name = `${ description.split(/\s+/).join('-').replace(/[^\w-]/g, '') }.jpg`;

    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, (Math.random() * 500), name));
  };
  const generateImgUrl = async (name, title, id) => {
    title = title.split(/\s+/).join('-').replace(/[^\w-]/g, '');

    return new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(resolve, (Math.random() * 500), `s3/bucket/images/${ id }/${ title }/${ name }`)
    );
  };

  const createPost = async (...args) => {
    console.log(`Posting scraped article data from arguments ... ["${ args.join('", "') }"]`);

    return new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(resolve, (Math.random() * 1500), { title: args[0] })
    );
  };

  const searchApi = {
    getNews: async (query) =>
      new Promise(resolve =>
        setTimeout(resolve, (Math.random() * 1500), {
        //articles: [],
          articles: [{
            title: '01) Lorem Ipsum',
            sourceUrl: 'foo/bar/baz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '02) Dolor sit amet',
            sourceUrl: 'biz/buzz/booz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '03) Lorem Ipsum',
            sourceUrl: 'foo/bar/baz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '04) Dolor sit amet',
            sourceUrl: 'biz/buzz/booz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '05) Lorem Ipsum',
            sourceUrl: 'foo/bar/baz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '06) Dolor sit amet',
            sourceUrl: 'biz/buzz/booz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '07) Lorem Ipsum',
            sourceUrl: 'foo/bar/baz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '08) Dolor sit amet',
            sourceUrl: 'biz/buzz/booz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '09) Lorem Ipsum',
            sourceUrl: 'foo/bar/baz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '10) Dolor sit amet',
            sourceUrl: 'biz/buzz/booz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '11) Lorem Ipsum',
            sourceUrl: 'foo/bar/baz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '12) Dolor sit amet',
            sourceUrl: 'biz/buzz/booz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }, {
            title: '13) Lorem Ipsum',
            sourceUrl: 'foo/bar/baz',
            id: crypto?.randomUUID?.(),
            publishedAt: new Date(Date.now() - (Math.random() * 14*24*3_600_000)).toUTCString(),
          }],
        })
      ),
  };
</script>
```